# Tracking Overlapping Emails

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to flag email traffic that may be going to the same recipients either on the same day or within the same few days to minimize overlaps.

Is there a Power Query script that I could run to flag these automatically as the data refreshes? I'd imagine it is GroupBy the Recipient to get a count of the total communications they're receiving per day, isolating those > 1 and than flagging those

Below is my data set in blue, desired output in yellow, and logic behind the result in grey.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "or within the same few days"? you have to set a specific days. How person 4 is flagged as they are getting mail on different days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below measure in your table.

> As you mentioned "few days" in your requirement, the duration of days is set in a variable in the measure. You can set any days there.

> - 0 will check for same day overlap
> - you can set it 1/2 or any number as per requirement

```
check_overlap_for_days = 

VAR days_to_check = 0 
-- 0 will check for same day overlap
-- you can set it 1/2 or any number as per requirement

VAR current_row_recipient = MIN(email_overlap[recipient])
VAR current_row_date = MIN(email_overlap[date])

VAR email_count =
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        ALL(email_overlap),
        email_overlap[recipient] = current_row_recipient
            && ABS(DATEDIFF(current_row_date,email_overlap[date],DAY)) <= days_to_check
    )
)

RETURN IF(email_count >= 2, "X", "")
```

Only Recipient and Email date considered here to define the overlap email. You can add other considerations like Team if it is required. The output is -

[image]